# displaying a div content side by side

Tags: html, styles

iam using a div  contents .This div is repeating number of times showing output as

2
any street
basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED

2
any street
basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED

like this . i need a display in side by side rather than displaying below.

```
.wfte_invoice-main {
    color: #73879C;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

please give me a solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

according to what I have understand, maybe you can use `display: flex` property and put your text in a paragraph tag like this:

```
<div class="your_container">
  <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
    2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
  </p>
  <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
    2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
  </p>
  ...
</div>

.your_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Link to the codesandbox: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-monad-9d7cm?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

A div is a block-element and block-elements are displayed below each others by default.

If you want to make them order in a row, just add

```
display: inline-block
```

to your div-class "wfte_invoice-main".

Another way would be wrapping a flex-box-container around your two divs.

```
<div class="wfte_invoice-container">
  <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
    2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
  </p>
  <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
    2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
  </p>
</div>
```

And add the following style:

```
 .wfte_invoice-container {
  display: flex;
  }
```

You can edit the look of your container by adding values for justify-content and align-items.